# Create Index On Azure Returns Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, clustered-index

I have a table with just over a million rows in Azure that I'm trying to add a clustered index to using the following SQL:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyIdxName
ON [MyApp].MyTable([MyColumn])
WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON)
ON [Primary]
```

When I do it through the web interface it runs for over an hour and then fails with the error:

```
Failed to read the status of the response
```

If I do it through SQL Management Studio it runs for a half hour and then fails with the error:

```
40552: The session has been terminated because of excessive transaction log 
space usage. Try modifying fewer rows in a single transaction.
```

I get what it's saying, but what can I do about it?  I want to create this clustered index, so how can I get around this transaction log size issue?

Thanks

Comment: Create a separate table with the desired clustered index, and move the data over in chunks, say 10,000 rows at a time. [Roughly similar concept to this](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes). Then drop the old table and rename the new one.

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same as Aaron Bertrand - not a fun solution, but it should work.

Comment: Yuck.  Ok, thanks.  If someone wants to make it an answer and I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try creating index with(online=on) option. This should prevent long table locks...

Answer (score 0):

The session killed because of the excessive transaction log space. I am not sure which performance tier you are, but upgrading to V12 will help solve this problem as I don't see throttling due to transaction log space and is limited by the available log space. 
You can do the following:
1. Upgrade to V12
2. Using sys.dm_db_partition_stats look for the total size of the table
3 using sys.database_files know the available log size
4. If the size of log is at least 1.5 -2x (just a rough number to make sure you don't hit log full) perform a Online index rebuild.